# How do I unquote a string with escaped characters?

Tags: json, quotes

I have a weird json with strigified jsons inside, like this:

```
{ "foo": "{\"bar\": \"bam\"}" }
```

I need to read the internal json, like:

```
{ "bar": "bam" }
```

Comment: I'm working in bash, so the first extraction was done using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

Answer (score 10):

It seems that it also can be solved in the command-line using jq with the `fromjson` builtin:

```
echo '{ "foo": "{\"bar\": \"bam\"}" }' | jq ".foo | fromjson"
```

or using `--raw-output`

```
echo '{ "foo": "{\"bar\": \"bam\"}" }' | jq --raw-output ".foo" | jq "."
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not "weird". It's just json containing another json string. Decode the parent json, extract the value of the `foo` key, decode that value, and you'll get your inner json:

```
orig = "{ \"foo\": \"{\\"bar\\": \\"bam\\"}\" }";
data = JSON.parse(orig);
foo = data.foo;
subdata = JSON.parse(foo);
alert(subdata.bar); // bam
```

Comment: You are right, that works perfectly, I got that using curl and extracted the quoted string using jq, and that made it more difficult, but it is easier that way.